# Bootstrap Datepicker problems

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to get bootstrap datepicker to work but it does not even show up.

example above code below.

```
$(function() {

    $('#txt_TkhMulaMohon').datepicker();

});




<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_TkhMulaMohon" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Did you add reference to `datepicker` plugin?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, I think that is the error... Even experienced programmer encounters this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, Include this bit in your javascript document:

```
function datepicker() {
    $('.txt_TkhMulaMohon').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',

    }).on('changeDate', function(e){
        $(this).attr('value', $('.txt_TkhMulaMohon').val());
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    }); 
}
```

On the input where you want to get the datepicker you add `onclick="datepicker();"`

Also I would change your selector to a class `.txt_TkhMulaMohon`

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.But, the Datepicker doesn't hide after selecting date.

Comment: Could you updat the code in your post so I can see what you did?